# Redefining memberfunctions of a static library?

Tags: c++, class, overriding, static-libraries, member-functions

I guess my question is quite simple but i can't figure out any solution:

Can I redefine memberfunctions of a class in a static library?

Example

My Library looks something like this:

**Library.h**

```
namespace mynamespace
{
     class A
     {
       public:   void randomfunction();
     }
}
```

**Library.cpp**

```
namespace mynamespace
{
    void A::randomfunction(){
       std::cout << "Random output!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

My program using this library:

**main.cpp**

```
using namespace mynamespace;

void A::randomfunction(){
  std::cout << "Super fancy output!" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a;
    a.randomfunction();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Including the library works fine and if I don't override the function my program compiles and works fine.
The problem is I need the normal version for most of my programs but sometimes I need it to do other stuff and i can't use inheritance because I have other classes in this library that refer to this class and I also don't want to make the other classes generic because then i always have to use inheritance even if i don't want to override the function :/

Comment: In short: No, you can't do so. Some libraries allow to 'override' weak function definitions, but that's for [tag:c] and uses special attributes and flags for linking.

Comment: Ok so i guess i have to use inheritance and generics to make this work as i want it, thank you =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a function in a static library and again differently in one of the other source files, you violate the [one definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: Ok I will just use generics for my other classes and use virtual functions in this one and override it then in a derived class.